# How to prevent expressjs adding trailing slash to static dir

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redirect

I am serving a static folder which contains an index.html as

```
app.use('/' + 'folder', express.static(srvFolder + 'folder'));
```

but when I browse to

```
example.com/folder
```

the index.html is successfully served but the url becomes

```
example.com/folder/
```

What is the best way to continue serving a static directory but without the trailing slash?

notes

- I understand that the / means it is being redirected to a folder
- There are 100s of sub folders with index files with the same issue
- If I set redirect:false then the index.html will no longer be served

Comment: you could just fix it in the browser using `history.replaceState`, or handle it in your js code with an initializing `path.replace(/\/$/,"")`

Comment: @dandavis hmm good point. These pages are beautifully free from js right now... so I'm reluctant... its fairly inevitable they won't stay that way so... maybe.